# What electronic part is this?

Tags: digital-logic, components

[image]

What electronic part is this? What does it do?
I've two emergency LED AC+DC light and found out they do not have any kind of transformer to lower the voltage from 230VAC. (obviously LEDs don't need that much voltage). Does this thing used instead of transformer? Or it only converts AC TO DC?

Comment: You are asking 2 questions here. Please don't do that. Remember that this site, needs focus within each topic. You have already asked [your LDR-related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/309753/) and questions about that topic should be confined to *that* question. In that question, the hysteresis you need at the threshold level does *not* require a capacitor. Hence your two problems are not related and should *not* be mixed in the same question. I suggest you remove any mention about the LDR switch from *this* question, before you accumulate down votes or other sanctions.

Comment: Note the schematic symbol on the PCB: it denotes a capacitor as answers have already shown.

Comment: It's a flux capacitor, same type as the one being used in the Delorean time machine.

Answer (score 5):

> What electronic part is this?

It's a film capacitor.

It looks most similar to a [Xicon metallized polypropylene cap](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/449/mpp-205792.pdf), but that much is guesswork. There are other manufacturers who make similar-looking caps, such as Panasonic, though Panasonic caps have the "M" Matsushita logo on them.

The 335 part of the number means 3300000 pF (5 = the number of zeroes) so 3.3 µF. The J probably means 5% tolerance, and the 400V part is its voltage tolerance.

Its size and voltage tolerance argue that it's metalized polypropylene. If it were some other dielectric type, it would probably have a lower voltage tolerance and be smaller. If it were film-and-foil rather than metalized film, it would be bigger, given the 3.3 µF capacity.

> What does it do?

Without seeing the rest of the circuit, we can only make guesses. I suggest that you trace the circuit out and post it as a schematic.

Comment: Do you want to say anything about the light switch?

Comment: @A_47: That should be a separate question. It is bad form to ask two different questions in a single post, particularly when the second is only tangentially related to the title question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a capacitor. Probablly part of a "capacitive dropper"

A capactive dropper is a cheap option for powering light loads but it has a couple of downsides.

1. There is no isolation. The low-voltage circuitry will be tied to one of the mains input terminals.
2. The power factor is terrible.
3. Output voltage is dependent on load current. Often there will be a dummy load resistor to make the load current more constant

So it is only suitable for very low power equipment where all current carrying parts can be well-insulated from the user.

Conversion of AC to DC will typically be handled by a rectifier after the dropper.

Unfortunately some shitty "direct from china" vendors have been known to use such capacitive droppers without ensuring sufficient isolation for the user. I've even heard of one rechargable lantern which was powered by a capacitive dropper and had a port for charging USB devices!

Answer (score 2):

**It's a capacitor**. The photo is a bit blurry, but I think its 3.3uF, 400V.

You can make a transformer-less power supply with capacitors and diodes.  It's cheap.  It's also kinda dangerous - there is no isolation barrier between the mains and the low voltage.  It is still possible to make a safe system using this approach, but it is trickier, because it is possible to get a lethal shock from any part of the circuit, including the nominally low voltage side.

Answer (score 0):

The writing on the component appears to be something like _CBB21__, 335J400V.

Best guess is a CBB 335j 400v Metallized Polypropylene Film Capacitor

"CBB" refers to Polypropylene.
The first digit of "2" means a Metalization structure.
"335" meaning 3.3uF.

Comment: Good info. It would be helpful to explain how you decoded the information from the part number sections. (E.g., how does one find out that CCB means Polypropylene)?